# C++ <type>*& in class function or struct error

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-keyword

Here is a part of my code:

```
class Node{
   public:
   Node* parent;
   Node* left;
   Node* right;
   int key;
};

(...)

/*
* Ps.: v1 is parent of v2!
* and assume that v1->parent is NULL
*/
void somefunction(Node*& v1,Node*& v2){
    (...)
    v2->parent = v1->parent; // The problem is here, more details below
    (...)
}
```

The problem is when I call `v2->parent`, because of the `<type>*&` in the argument of `somefunction()`, the compiler interprets that `v2->parent` is equal `v1` (who is v2's father), and it modifies `v1` to `NULL`, but I just want modify `v2->parent` value and not `v1`.

PS.: I need to use `<type>*&` in some parts below my code, I can't just modify the argument type.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're probably calling the function like this:

```
somefunction(v2->parent, v2);
```

That means that `v2->parent` inside the function is precisely the same object as `v1` inside the function. When you set `v2->parent` to `v1->parent` (which is `NULL`), you are modifying `v1` also.

You say you can't modify the argument types, but I suggest that you do. Having a reference to a pointer is a pretty bad sign. It seems like your code needs a redesign.

The alternative is that you copy `v2->parent` before you pass it to the function:

```
Node* v1 = v2->parent;
somefunction(v1, v2);
```

Now the `v1` inside the function is this copy of `v2->parent` and won't modify the original.

Comment: +1 I have no idea *how* you got that from the code posted, but it was impressive. I got lost trying to parse the last paragraph, which is where I think you ultimately gleaned this answer.